# How do I get two servers using subdomain urls to talk to each other?

Tags: linux, apache, dns

I have two Ubuntu 12:04 EC2 servers doing their stuff. They are accessed as 'live.fooville.com' and 'dev.fooville.com' (I made those up but they are comparable names).

I can access them fine and their services are performing as intended. However, I can't get one to talk to the other using the normal url:

From my home PC:

```
~ $ wget --no-check-certificate https://live.fooville.com
--2012-12-10 18:33:54--  https://live.fooville.com/
Resolving live.fooville.com... xx.xxx.xx.92
Connecting to live.fooville.com|xx.xxx.xx.92|:443... connected.
```

From dev.fooville.com:

```
dev.fooville.com ~ $ wget https://live.fooville.com/
--2012-12-10 08:31:32--  https://live.fooville.com/
Resolving orb.evanidus.com... 127.0.1.1
Connecting to orb.evanidus.com|127.0.1.1|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

Using wget on dev.fooville.com to my other servers not on the same domain works fine eg:

```
dev.fooville.com ~ $ wget --no-check-certificate https://www.paulwhippconsulting.com
--2012-12-10 08:38:26--  https://www.paulwhippconsulting.com/
Resolving www.paulwhippconsulting.com... 111.118.174.73
Connecting to www.paulwhippconsulting.com|111.118.174.73|:443... connected.
```

I can work around the problem by using the IP address rather than the domain name so it seems that dev.fooville.com thinks that live.fooville.com is local and does not do a dns lookup to find the correct address.

Maybe I'm completely wrong... it would be nice to know what is going on so that I can correct it and use the normal domain names of the servers at the command line. I tried google and could not find anything helpful.

Comment: Obviously a domain resolving to IP address 127.0.1.1 is suspicious right away. Have you checked `/etc/hosts` for incorrect entries?

Answer (score 0):

Like Celada commented, check /etc/hosts. Basically you need to do an nslookup from dev.fooville.com to live.fooville.com , if you get a 127.0.1.1 response that simply means your dns service or /etc/hosts considers  live.fooville.com pointing to 127.0.1.1, so you may need to put the correct entry on dns service, if you are using just /etc/hosts try putting   there , To test restart dns client service( i am using dnsmasq)  and try to curl/wget it.